# How can I run emacs and terminal at the same time?

Tags: emacs, compilation

I've been opening emacs from the terminal but every time I want to compile my c program, i have to quit emacs first, compile it on terminal, then re-open emacs afterward again to edit some more.

Is there a simpler way to do this so I can keep emacs open while also compiling stuff on terminal?

I know this has something to do with entering shell mode but I'm not too familiar with that or editing the init file as im really new to emacs and still trying to get the hang of it

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Opening two terminals would be an easy way.

Comment: you can type `emacs file.c &` if you are using Linux or else you can use the terminal from emacs with `M-x shell`

Comment: You can put emacs into background with `C-z`, and reopen it from the shell with `%emacs`. Using an X-aware version of Emacs is another option.

Comment: the m-x shell worked great for me, thanks guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To compile your program while inside Emacs, type `M-x compile` and enter the compilation command.  As a bonus, any errors or warnings in the output become links to the corresponding line in the source code.

Once your program is compiled, there are a few different ways to run it.  If it's a non-interactive program, you may find that `M-!` (for running a shell command, waiting for it to finish, and displaying its output in a buffer) is sufficient.  Otherwise, you may want to run a shell inside Emacs.  You can do that with `M-x eshell`.  (Some people prefer `M-x shell`; try both and see what you like.)

---

Alternatively, if you want to temporarily leave Emacs and go back to the terminal, you can type `C-z` to put Emacs in the background.  To go back from the shell to Emacs, type `%` or `fg` (for "foreground").  To check whether Emacs is currently running in the background, type `jobs`.

Answer (score 3):

Alternatively, it's straight-forward to run `M-x ansi-term` to have a functioning terminal inside of an Emacs buffer. It's nice having a working, interactive terminal in Emacs but also to be able to navigate that terminal output using your normal Emacs key bindings.

I use this [this package](https://github.com/purcell/exec-path-from-shell) to make sure all my environment variables are loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Some operational notes:

When I'm editing something in Emacs and in need of a terminal, my usual procedure is to split vertically 'C-x 2' or horizontally 'C-x 3' in order to be able to open a terminal emulator (either 'M-x eshell' or 'M-x shell') side by side with the actual window. From here it is possible go forward and backward with 'C-x o' or 'C-u C-x o'  as needed. This allows to continue editing while something is running visibly on the near window.

In rare cases where these emulators dont work exactly as the real OS terminal, we can split and use the native thing without layer or emulation 'C-x term RET RET' . Unfortunatly, in the later case, it is not possible to cycle between the framed windows (with 'C-x o') . Here, the exit command is required to be able to operate normally with emacs.

Comment: You do not need to exit a terminal process to interact with Emacs. Just switch to `term-line-mode` with `C-c C-j`. Switch back to `term-char-mode` with `C-c C-k` to resume sending (most) input directly to the inferior process. You can alternatively (in char mode) use `C-c` in place of the `C-x` prefix, so for your specific example just use `C-c o`. This is pointed out in the manual: `C-h i g (emacs) Term Mode`

Comment: You are correct. That is a good tip. In fact, 'C-c C-j / C-c C-k' is very usefull in that situation. I normally use something like 'M-: (info "(emacs)The topic")' to jump to known topics, but I see that your combination  'C-h i g (emacs) The Topic ' is faster and much better, specially because it has command completion.